# Possible alternatives or solution to reading and writing large objects with Gson java

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I'm attempting to read and write an object through gson. Early in the project this was completely viable and doing great, but as I wrote more data for that object I eventually ran across something along the lines of this:

I can't seem to grab the full stacktrack seeing as it overflows my console within milliseconds, but I've pastebinned everything my console could grab: http://pastebin.com/v36d5qua

If there is a solution to this, or possibly just a better api for this purpose I would really appreciate some advice.

Current usage: http://pastebin.com/2Yk2v0Tm

```
            GsonUtil.save(player, Player.class, new File("./resources/players/"+player.getId()+".json"));
```

P.S I'm new to java & this site in general, if I have misleading tags, title etc please let me know.

Comment: You'll need to post the entire stack trace; the snippet you pasted is incomplete and doesn't contain the actual exception that was thrown.

Comment: That's quite difficult, as it completely flooded my console with those same four lines, but I will display everything possible right now: http://pastebin.com/v36d5qua

Comment: Unfortunately, still incomplete.  I do have a guess though, do you have any recursive references in your player object?  (Something like `player.team.players[0] == player`?)  Because if so, GSON will probably attempt to make some infinitely nested JSON.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but unfortunately no, nothing of the sort in my player class

Comment: Then please post a [simple, self-contained compilable example](http://sscce.org/) so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use gson. It's slow, it's buggy, it's inconvenient to use. Just use org.json - http://theoryapp.com/parse-json-in-java/